# Connect Transparency to keyframe animation Maya MelPython

Tags: python, maya, mel

I have a workaround to connect the transparency of a Metrial to the keyframe bar in Maya. I create a new Material press "s" for a keyframe got to the keyframe 10, set the transparency to 0 and press again "s".

So you are able to fade the transparency beteween the 1 and 10 keyframe.

I want to script this in python and I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I've made. I tested it with basic Maya materials, but it should work for any material wich has a `transparency` attribute (note that it won't work for surface shaders as the transparency attribute is called `outTransparency`, but you could fix it by changing the function so you could also pass it the attribute name).

I got the `getShaderFrom (obj)` function in [this topic](http://forums.cgsociety.org/showthread.php?t=842021) and just converted it in Python (it's in MEL).

I made it as simple and detailled as possible but it could probably be optimized. Anyway, hope this answered your question!

```
from maya import cmds

def getShaderFrom (obj):
    '''
    List all materials for the given object
    '''
    # List the shapes of the given object
    shapes = cmds.ls (obj, objectsOnly = 1, dagObjects = 1, shapes = 1)
    # List the shading engines connected to the shapes
    shadingEngines = cmds.listConnections (shapes, type = "shadingEngine")
    # List the materails connected to the shading engines
    rawMaterials = cmds.ls ((cmds.listConnections (shadingEngines)), materials = 1)
    # Remove duplicated occurences of materials
    materials = []
    for mat in rawMaterials:
        if mat not in materials:
            materials.append(mat)

    return materials


def keyTransparency (startFrame, endFrame, material):
    '''
    Will key the transparency of
    a given materials between
    selected frames
    '''
    # Set transparency value at 1
    cmds.setAttr (material + ".transparency", 1,1,1, type = "double3")
    # Add a keyframe at last frame
    cmds.setKeyframe (material, attribute = "transparency", time = endFrame, inTangentType = "linear", outTangentType = "linear")
    # Add a keyframe at first frame
    cmds.setKeyframe (material, attribute = "transparency", time = startFrame, inTangentType = "linear", outTangentType = "linear")
    # Set transparency value at 0
    cmds.setAttr (material + ".transparency", 0,0,0, type = "double3")


def doKeyTransparencyForMaterials (startTime, endTime):
    '''
    Main function
    Call functions: 'getShaderFrom', 'keyTransparency'
    '''
    if ((not isinstance(startTime, int)) or (not isinstance(endTime, int))):
        cmds.error ("You must provide start and end frame numbers (int).")
    # List selected objects
    selection = cmds.ls (selection = 1)
    if len(selection) == 0:
        cmds.error ("Nothing is selected.")
    # List all materials
    for obj in selection:
        materials = getShaderFrom (obj)
        # Key transparency
        for mat in materials:
            keyTransparency (startTime, endTime, mat)

    print "Transparency has been successfully keyed for: " + (", ".join(materials)) + "\n",


doKeyTransparencyForMaterials (1, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

######### Delete all existing Shader ############## 
cmds.delete (cmds.ls(type='shadingDependNode'))
cmds.delete (cmds.ls(type='shadingEngine'))
######### Delete all existing Shader ##############

######### Delete all Keyframes between 0 and 20 ##############
cmds.setKeyframe( 'lambert1', t='1', at='transparency'  )
cmds.cutKey ( t=(0,20) )
######### Delete all Keyframes ##############

#create Blau shader
Blau = cmds.shadingNode('phong', asShader=True, n='Blau', )
cmds.setAttr(Blau + '.color', 0.163,0.284,0.5)


#create KeyFrame Transparency ###Blau####
cmds.setKeyframe( 'Blau', t='1', at='transparency'  )
cmds.setAttr ( 'Blau.transparency', 1,1,1, type = "double3")
cmds.setKeyframe( 'Blau', t='15', at='transparency' )

######### update Time to 2 and back to 0  ##############
cmds.currentTime ( 2, update=True )
cmds.currentTime ( 0, update=True )
######### update Time to 2 and back to 0  ##############
```

The setKeyFrame for lambert1  line is just to make the script running if no Key exists before.

I adjust the current time because your material is shown transparent if you apply it the first time.

PS: Blau is Blue in German